# Zapier Custom Action doesn't pass through data from a dynamic field select list

Tags: rest, dynamic, field, zapier

For an action I use a dynamic field containing a list of users (ids / labels). I collect the users via Rest API and they are presented in the UI.

[image]

I defined the list in the dynamic field code like:

```
const options = {
    url: 'https://<mysite>.ngrok.io/rest/1.0/<my endpoint>?expand=users',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${bundle.authData.api_key}`
    }
}

return z.request(options)
    .then((response) => {
        response.throwForStatus();

    return {
      key: 'coverers',
      label: 'Coverers for automatic reassigns',
      placeholder: 'Choose a coverer',
      choices: response.json.users,
      list: true
    }
});
```

In the API request for the action I define the "coverers" property and it is filled with an array of the size of the number of users I add in the UI. But the values are all empty objects [{}, {}, {}]. The code for this is:

```
    const options = {
    url: 'https://<my site>.ngrok.io/rest/1.0/<my endpoint>',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Autorization': `Bearer ${bundle.authData.api_key}`
    },
    params: {

    },
    body: {
        'startDate': bundle.inputData.startDate,
        'endDate': bundle.inputData.endDate,
        'coverers': bundle.inputData.coverers,
        'message': bundle.inputData.message
    }
}

return z.request(options)
    .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = response.json;

    // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them

    return results;
});
```

The rest api endpoint for the dynamic field returns:

```
[{
    "value": "xxxxx0c1c5e69a1",
    "sample": "xxxxx0c1c5e69a1",
    "label": "Ad Mihn"
},
{
    "value": "xxxxx0da21fdb29",
    "sample": "xxxxx0da21fdb29",
    "label": "Barbi Queue"
},
{
    "value": "xxxxx0da389dbb1",
    "sample": "xxxxx0da389dbb1",
    "label": "Mark Ating"
}]
```

Obviously the selected users are not correctly translated, but what am I missing? How can I get the selected user information?

Comment: Are you able to display field with the select options in Zapier UI?

Comment: Yes, and miraculously it worked next morning. I created a new zap and then it worked. I don't know, maybe something was not updated in the Zapier system.